# Bar chart from datagridview values

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I want to plot bar chart based on my `DataGridView` rows.How can I achieve that.The problem is it is plotting fine but not based on the rows present in `DataGridView`.The value in `DataGridView` is coming from the stored procedure based on the date as the parameter. [image]

```
For Count As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2
    Chart1.Series(0).Points.AddXY(DataGridView1.Item(0, Count).Value, DataGridView1.Item(1, Count).Value)
    Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.IsLabelAutoFit = False
    Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = -70
Next
```

Comment: The chart looks like a `Column` type not `Bar` type. Try changing the chart type for the `Series(0)`. Also change `DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2` to `DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1`.

Comment: Chart1.Series(0).Points.Clear() Adding before For Next worked for me......Thanks for your response